# How to use equal condition in Handelbars (HBS) with each condition?

Tags: handlebars.js, registerhelper

I am using Handlebar and try to use if condition with equal like `if(value.A==value.B)`.

Below is the code where i am trying this.

```
<div>
    {{#each Data}}
     {{#ifCond value.A value.B}}
               <tr>
            <td>{{value.C}}</td>
            <td>{{value.D}}</td>
            <td>{{value.E}}</td>
            
        </tr>
     {{/ifCond}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

I have used below code but it is giving `TypeError: hbs.registerHelper is not a function`

The code is in app.js :-

```
var expressHbs =  require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs.engine({ defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

var hbs = expressHbs.create({});
hbs.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1, v2, options) {
    if(v1 === v2) {
      return options.fn(this);
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here.

First, as your error indicates, `registerHelper` is *not* a function on the instance object returned by `expressHbs.create({})`. The returned object is an instance of an `ExpressHandlebars` object and this is *not* the same thing as the Handlebars library which has a `registerHelper` function.

The way to register helpers on an instance of `ExpressHandlebars` is via the configuration object passed to `.create()`:

```
var hbs = expressHbs.create({
  helpers: {
    ifCond(v1, v2, options) {
      if (v1 === v2) { return options.fn(this); }
      return options.inverse(this);
    },
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, this change alone will not suffice. It will lead to the Error:

> Missing helper: "ifCond"

The issue here is that we have created the `ifCond` helper on the `hbs` instance, but the `hbs` instance is not the one we are setting as our Express View Engine.

Our Express View Engine is set with the result of a call to `expressHbs.engine` with some configuration properties.

Express-Handlebars gives us the option of using the `.engine` function to construct an engine object or the `.create` function to create instances of `ExpressHandlebars`, each with its own `.engine` object.

In your example, you are not doing anything with the `hbs` instance. Your helpers need to be added to the configuration passed in your `expressHbs.engine` call:

```
app.engine(
  ".hbs",
  expressHbs.engine({
    defaultLayout: "layout",
    extname: ".hbs",
    helpers: {
      ifCond(v1, v2, options) {
        if (v1 === v2) { return options.fn(this); }
        return options.inverse(this);
      },
    },
  })
);
```

`var hbs = expressHbs.create({});` can be removed.